# problem with sql lines, conflicts and more

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am new on this website, I have to enter this SQL instructions  in my DB but I can't solve the error shown below:

```
*create table category ( id int(10) primary key not null auto_increment, name varchar(50));

create table product ( product_id int(10) primary key not null auto_increment, name varchar(50) , price double(10,2), category_id int(10), description varchar(1000));

alter table product add constraint product_ctgy_id_fk foreign key(category_id) references category( id);

create table userorder(order_id  int(10) primary key not null auto_increment, user_id int(10) , price double(10,2));

create table user(user_id int(10) primary key not null auto_increment, fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10), email_id varchar(50), phone int(10));

alter table userorder add constraint order_user_id_fk foreign key(user_id) references user(user_id);
//alter table product add column description varchar(1000);

create table orderItems ( item_id int(10) primary key not null auto_increment, name varchar(50), quantity int(2), order_id int(10));

alter table orderItems add constraint order_id_fk foreign key(order_id) references userorder(order_id);
 alter table userorder add column order_date date;

 alter table user modify phone varchar(10);

alter table userorder modify order_date timestamp;

 alter table orderItems add column hotness varchar(10);

 
 alter table user add column address varchar(100);


insert into category values (1,"APPETIZERS");
insert into category values (2,"Soups and Salads"); 
insert into category values (3,"Tandoori Breads");
insert into category values (4,"Rice and Biryani");
insert into category values (5,"Tandoori Specialities");
insert into category values (6,"Chicken Entrees");
insert into category values (7,"Lamb Entrees");
insert into category values (8,"Sea Food");
insert into category values (9,"Vegetable Delights");
insert into category values (10,"Specials");
insert into category values (11,"Beverages");
insert into category values (12,"Beers");
insert into category values (13,"Deserts"); 
insert into category values (14,"Side Orders");
insert into product values (1, "VEGETABLE SAMOSA",2.95, 1,"Crisp patties filled with mildly spiced potatoes and peas");
insert into product values (2, "VEGETABLE PAKORA",2.95, 1,"Mixed Vegetable Fritters dipped in batter and fried");
insert into product values (3, "CHICKEN PAKORA",6.95, 1,"Boneless chicken dipped in spiced batter and fried");
insert into product values (4, "CHEESE PAKORA",5.95, 1,"Delicately spiced fried cheese fritters");
insert into product values (5, "FISH PAKORA",8.95, 1,"Fish filets dipped in Spiced batter and fried");
insert into product values (6, "CHICKEN SOUP",4.95, 2,"Indian style, lightly spiced");
insert into product values (7, "MULLIGATAWNY SOUP",3.95, 2,"Delicately Spiced Lentil Soup Garnished with Rice & Chicken");
insert into product values (8, "LENTIL SOUP",2.95, 2,"Mildly spiced");
insert into product values (9, "Vegeterian Salad",3.95, 2,"Lettuce, cheese, cilantro, cucumber, tomatoes");
insert into product values (10, "KACHUMBER/CHICK PEA SALAD",2.95, 2,"Cucumbers, Onions, Tomatoes, Cilantro, Chickpeas & Lemon");
insert into product values(117,"ASSORTED APPETIZERS ",8.95,1,"KABAB, SAMOSA, PAKORA, CHICKEN PAKORA, ONION BHAJI");
insert into product values(118,"PANEER TIKKA (CHEEESE)",12.95,1,"Marinated in spices, cooked in clay over, sautÃ©ed in bell pepper & onion");
insert into product values(119,"CHILI CHICKEN",13.95,1,"Boneless chicken sautÃ©ed with onion and Bell Pepper");
insert into product values(120,"ONION BHAJI",3.95,1,"Chopped onions dipped in batter and fried");
insert into product values(121,"GULAB JAMUN",3.95,13,"Indian Milk Cheese Balls, Fried & soaked in honey syrup");
insert into product values(122,"KHEER",3.95,13,"Indian Rice Pudding");
insert into product values(123,"PISTACHIO KULFI",4.95,13,"Indian Ice Cream With Pistachios");
insert into product values(124,"MANGO KULFI",4.95,13,"Indian Ice Cream With Mango");
insert into product values(125,"RAITA",2.5,14,"Cultured Yogurt with Cucumbers, Carrots & Spices");
insert into product values(126,"Plain Yogurt",2.5,14,"");
insert into product values(127,"MANGO CHUTNEY",2.5,14,"");
insert into product values(128,"HOT PICKEL",1.95,14,"");
insert into product values(129,"PAPADDAM",1.25,14,"");*
```

**But an error appears "CONFLICT WITH "TABLE" and Entity name expected.**

How can i solve this? I need to create that column cause my .war needs it. Otherwise it will return and 500 error.

Comment: On which line? Run the statements one at a time to narrow down the root cause.

Comment: Tip: Consider using `VARCHAR(255)` as a default general-purpose string-type field and only override this with longer or shorter constraints if you have a compelling reason. Many MySQL installations will silently truncate any data which doesn’t fit, resulting in lost data, user complaints, and other serious issues. Names and email addresses are quite frequently surprisingly long, so accommodating these is important.

Comment: Error is on line 9. "CONFLICT WITH "TABLE" and Entity name expected.

Comment: Can you trim out all the lines but the one that causes the error? Help us out here. If it's not relevant to the question, strip it.

Comment: create table user(user_id int(10) primary key not null auto_increment, fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10), email_id varchar(50), phone int(10));


 this line is the problem

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line. Are you sure that's the issue? Can you make a **minimal example** that produces the problem?

Comment: These are MySQL statements. Are you using the MySQL database?

Comment: in mysql 8 it runs all when you disable the alter table product add column description varchar(1000); correctly with #

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the mySql reserved keywords:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U

Seems like you trying to create table `user` with is also mySql keyword.

Try to encapsulate  table name:

```
create table `user`(
```

Or, if it possible, rename it to smth like `users`